# Extracting image from QMediaPlayer Video

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, video-processing

i am using Qt Creator to implement an application that reads a video and by clicking on a button i will save the frame that is being showed. Then i will process that frame with Opencv.

Having a video being displayed with QmediaPlayer, how can i extract a frame from the video? I should then be able to convert that frame to a Mat image in Matlab.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer();
QVideoProbe *probe = new QVideoProbe;

connect(probe, SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(QVideoFrame)), this, SLOT(processFrame(QVideoFrame)));

probe->setSource(player); // Returns true, hopefully.
```

processFrame slot:

```
void processFrame(QVideoFrame const&) {
  if (isButtonClicked == false) return;
  isButtonClicked = false;

  ...
  process frame
  ...

}
```

[QVideoProbe reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html)

[QVideoFrame reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html)

You can use QVideoFrame::bits() to process image with OpenCV

Comment: Nice thanks!! And..do i have to define the processFrame function? where?

Comment: ProcessFrame is a simple slot. You can define it everywhere as any function,  just connect this function(slot) to QVideoProbe::videoFrameProbed.

Comment: Also you can use QVideoProbe with qcamera :)